# Git pull logs : what does the % mean with rename operation log?

Tags: git

Maybe it is not related to the rename operation, but if so, what does the '57%' (at the end of the line) represent?

Git logs after a 'git pull' on branch master:

```
rename src/components/{Client/ClientShow/ClientShowFiguresTabs.jsx =>
   Tier/TierShowFiguresTabs.jsx} (57%)
```

Comment: Git doesn't record the file renames in the repo. It attempts to detect them on the reporting time (f.e. when `git log` is executed). The percentage represents how much of the two files are similar (common lines). It uses a threshold of similar lines to detect renames even when there are also changes in the file content. Sometimes it reports as renames files that look similar but are not related in any way.

Comment: See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff--Mltngt.